# Display Pop up Window

Tags: c#, jquery

In My requirement I have 1 Dropdown and 2 buttons. 
    •   Select Config File - Dropdown
        • Create New
    •   View Config File - Button
    •   Modify Config File - Button
    Here Select Config File is Drop down.If user clicks drop down "Create New" Option will come. If User clicks "Create New", then Pop up window should come.
    Here is my code for Pop up window under ModelPopup.aspx,

```
              <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
              <asp:Button ID="ADDROWBTN" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" />
              <asp:Button ID="SAVENEWBTN" runat="server" Text="Save as New" />
              <asp:Button ID="SAVEBTN" runat="server" Text="Save" />
      </div>
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id*=btnvcf]").click(function () {
                ShowPopup();
                return false;
            });
        });
        function ShowPopup() {
            $("#PopUp").dialog({
                title: "GridView",
                width: 450,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
        }
    </script>
    </form>
```

Is this code correct. How can I display the Popup with this code.

Comment: You can also use the button's `onClientClick` to call the function and display the popup window.

Comment: And what's problem you face to display the popup window ?

Comment: Its not displaying anything. And complete page is not displaying now.

Comment: Where is your `#Popup` code ?

Comment: Didn't write any code for #Popup.

Comment: where I have to write this code

Comment: Without writing code for `#Popup` how you can display the `Popup` Window ?

Comment: where I have to write the code PopUp